# Kubuntu fresh Installation and breeze icons are missing in GNome application style, so dolphin looks ugly

Tags: kubuntu

I have a fresh kubuntu installation and breeze themes icons are missing.

[image]

I already have cleared my cache by moving .kde and .cache.
I have already tried to change theme but no success.

My main concern is that dolphin looks very different then it should. See dolphin screen-shot.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?